# Layout do meta dificulta visualização da votação efetuada

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Quando damos um `up vote` aqui no **Meta Stackvoverflow**, não dá pra saber (se eu esqueçer) se eu já dei um voto a favor ou não, por conta do layout.

Vejam:

[image: Com voto a favor]

[image: Sem votos]

Será que não seria melhor para usabilidade se a cor da seta votada não ficasse mais destacada (se isso for possível de alguma forma)?

Comment: Eu consigo ver bem aqui...

Comment: Será que é só questão de costume? Mas o Laranja não precisa de costume, precisa?

Comment: Costume?! Não entendi

Comment: "Costume" de se acostumar com o layout, com a tipografia, essas coisas...

Comment: Ah, deve ser. eu nunca tive problemas com esse layout do Meta.

Comment: Agora todo mundo sabe que uso o notepad++, winscp, sublime text e windows (runidows) kkkk

Comment: Ao menos não usas IE :P

Comment: Já vi muitas reclamações com relação ao layout do SO e/ou do Meta, como o contraste da cor dos links, o espaçamento do <h1>, dentre outros, mas essa é a primeira vez que vejo alguém dizendo que não consegue ver bem a cor da seta já clicada ou não. Estou apenas fazendo uma constatação.

Comment: Concordo com você. Acho que o contraste das setas no meta é baixo, e um taanto difícil de distinguir. E também acho que o contraste da cor dos links é baixo demais.

Comment: Poderia destacar com a cor vermelha, no mesmo tom do vermelho dos links